# SQL query to get all data for a particular user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

`Users (idk, surnamek, namek, logink)`,

`Measurements (idm, date, weight, #idk)`

I need to create a query to get all measurements for a particular logink.

Comment: i get 'column m.idk does not exist' error even though it exists. Trying to find solution but thanks for help, its something

Comment: what is # before column name? `#idk` in table Measurements

Comment: idk is foreign key from users table, its representing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **[inner join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)**:

```
SELECT m.* FROM Measurements AS m INNER JOIN Users AS u ON u.idk = m.idk WHERE u.logink = ###;
```